# Which monitor is used to show the booting screen?

Tags: display, startup, mac-mini, big-sur

When I am booting my mac mini, how does it pick which of the three monitors it uses to show the apple logo and password screen on? (This is not necessarily the same screen declared as the primary for the menu bar.)

I have three monitors that are positioned like a TIE Fighter, and I would prefer not to have to look at the boot info sideways as it is starting up. Based on the answer, I should be able to determine a method by which proper screen can be obtained.

Comment: I can't find a plist file in /Library/Preferences that contains the name of the display. It may be something like the order that the ports are scanned. You could try plugging the one you want first and rebooting, then add the others.

Comment: I does not appear to be port order. Since my mac mini is behind my monitors (and against a wall), it is much less inconvenient to deal with the sideway monitor than unplugging/plugging them.

Answer (score 1):

The Mac mini models, that support up to 3 displays, normally use one of the USB-C ports for the display with the initial Apple logo. The HDMI port would only be used for the initial Apple logo display when there are no USB-C port connected displays. I can only assume that if three displays were connected, then the same USB-C port connected display would always be the initial Apple logo display. In other words, you not going to know which of the two USB-C port connected displays will be chosen for the initial Apple logo until you turn on the Mac. And, that this choice would be consistent.

Comment: I've seen similar with old Mac Pros, to the point that once it's chosen its 'favourite', after that you might as well move the monitors around to match your preference. You can't fight it ;)

Comment: I swapped the USB port on two of the monitors and it had no effect on the screen that was chosen. I will try moving the monitors again and see if that will make it stick once they have been configured.

Comment: Are the two monitors the same model?